# Как удалить кнопку из фрейма?

Tags: java, swing

Как удалить кнопку с фрейма?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JButton button = new JButton();
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(500, 500);
frame.setVizible(true);
```

А теперь, как мне удалить кнопку из фрейма?

Comment: `frame.getContentPane().remove(button);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем метод **remove**:

```
frame.remove(button);
```

или

```
button.getParent().remove(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй `Remove`:

```
panel.remove(button);
```